# Changing geographic coordinate system of feature class in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.4, feature-class

How do I make these two feature classes compatible in ArcMap 10.4?

(1)  --> 
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile:  C:\Users\craigugoretz\Desktop\CA_counties\CA_counties.shp 
Geometry Type:  Polygon 
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984 
Datum:  D_WGS_1984 
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich 
Angular Unit:   Degree

(2) --> 
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Shapefile:  C:\Users\craigugoretz\Desktop\NHD\WBDHU12.shp 
Geometry Type:  Polygon 
Coordinates have Z values:  No 
Coordinates have measures:  No

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983 
Datum:  D_North_American_1983 
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich 
Angular Unit:   Degree

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour].  If you search on the topic "NADCON" especially in tandem with "ArcGIS", you'll likely find a great deal of documentation.  You can then **edit** your question to include relevant details of what you have tried, and whatever difficulty you have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Load those layers in ArcMap, then click on one of them (right button), click "export data" and save your layer with coordinate system from other layer.

Comment: This may not work correctly without specifying a transformation (which is the same step needed to use the [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) utility.

Comment: If they line up fine, you can use this workflow. If the two layers seem offset around a meter, then do as @Vince suggests and set a transformation. Try NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5.